# Refresh b2Body's collision

Tags: iphone, box2d

How can I refresh b2Body's state in the world? I whould like to recalculate all collisions of my b2Body at specific moment. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'recalculate collisions'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem:

```
void FixtureContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold)
{
    contact->ResetFriction();

}
```